# Proper singleton class to use CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm trying to create a singleton class which works with an `NSManagedObjectContext`.

This is the class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PersistenceService{
    init(){}
    // MARK: - Core Data stack
    static var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    static var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "frazeit")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    static func saveContext () {
        let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext

        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.parent = mainContext

        privateContext.perform {
            if privateContext.hasChanges {
                do {
                    try privateContext.save()
                } catch {
                    let nserror = error as NSError
                    fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

In some occasion, it does not push changes into the persistent store, while the app is open the persistent container is changed but when I re-run the app changes are gone. What's the right way to save the changes into the persistent store.

This the class that does not work properly:

```
class func add(word: String, quotes:[Quotes], language: String){
    for item in quotes {
        if let phrase = item.phrase, let author = item.author {
            let quote = CachedQuotes(context: PersistenceService.context)
            quote.phrase = phrase
            quote.date = Date() as NSDate
            quote.keyword = word
            quote.language = language
            quote.author = author
            PersistenceService.saveContext()
        }

    }
}
```

I call it to save quotes which are fetched from the network:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    let quotes =  CachedQuotes.getAllQuotes()
    //Prints the number of saved records which is 0 now
    self.getQuote { (result, error) in
        if let qoutes = result?.quotes {
            CachedQuotes.add(word: "friend", quotes: qoutes, language: "en")
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let quotes =  CachedQuotes.getAllQuotes()
    //Prints the number of saved records which is 10 now
}
```

But when I re-run the app, nothing is saved into the persistance container.

**UPDATE:**
The code below works now

```
static func saveContext () {
        let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        privateContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        privateContext.parent = mainContext
        privateContext.perform {
            do {
                try privateContext.save()
                mainContext.perform({
                    do {
                        try mainContext.save()
                    } catch {
                        let nserror = error as NSError
                        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

First it saves the private quoue then saves the main.

Comment: Don't use a singleton for CoreData, use dependency injection.

Comment: @trapper why dependency injection is better and I should not use singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext

let privateContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
privateContext.parent = mainContext
```

You edit a context and then save the same context to persist the changes. Creating a child context to `.viewContext` and saving said child context does not save the `.viewContext` itself, where you made changes.

If you want to use background queues, first set [var automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent: Bool](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1845237-automaticallymergeschangesfrompa) on the `.viewContext` where you want to receive changes from the background queue. Then you create a background context, set on it the same persistentStoreCoordinator from `.viewContext`, make changes on it and then save the background queue.

Using `privateContext.perform` is a good start. You can do better if you wrap the changes to quote in a perform through the context in which the quote was created in the first place, so you access quote through the same thread the context uses.

Comment: Note: You don‘t need to create a private queue to save `viewContext`, where you currently make your changes. If you create a private queu, set it up so on save changes flow to viewContext AND make changes to the private queue, THEN you have to save this private queue. Saving a queue without before changing it is senseless since it does not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the singleton from Apple's [Refreshing and Maintaining Your App Using Background Tasks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks?language=objc) sample.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class PersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer {
    private static let lastCleanedKey = "lastCleaned"

    static let shared: PersistentContainer = {
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(ColorTransformer(), forName: NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: ColorTransformer.self)))

        let container = PersistentContainer(name: "ColorFeed")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (desc, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error)")
            }

            print("Successfully loaded persistent store at: \(desc.url?.description ?? "nil")")
        }

        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)

        return container
    }()

    var lastCleaned: Date? {
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: PersistentContainer.lastCleanedKey) as? Date
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: PersistentContainer.lastCleanedKey)
        }
    }

    override func newBackgroundContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let backgroundContext = super.newBackgroundContext()
        backgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy(merge: NSMergePolicyType.mergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicyType)
        return backgroundContext
    }
}
```

Personally I prefer passing the `NSPersistentContainer` around via dependency injection but it requires a lot more effort.